# How to strip html tags out of xml generated by builder in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xml, builder, strip

Here is my situation.  I'm trying to create a valid rss feed for an itunes podcast from an existing project.  It's a rails application that allows uploading of mp3 radio shows to for listening on the site.  I want to take all entries in the database and create an rss feed out of it.  I'm using a builder file and everything is working fine.  I noticed though that there's html tags stored in the database from a text editor.  for example strong tags and span tags are getting put inside of my xml when the feed is output.  Is there a way to strip that stuff out in the controller or in the xml builder?

My controller:

```
class PodcastsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @podcasts = Event.find(:all, :order => "date DESC", :conditions => ['radio = ?', 1])
        respond_to do |format|
      format.xml 
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tags are very simple, you could just use a regular expression to strip them out. For example:

```
"<html>Hello <b>world</b>.</html>".gsub(/<.+?>/, '')
=> "Hello world."
```

If it's more complex than that, it might make sense to load it in nokogiri and extract the text nodes.